# Why are my doctrine parameters not working ? Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I am making a symfony application with doctrine.
I'm using a queryBuilder to fetch some information from the database, however, I cannot bind parameters to my query.

I'm using this repository method to fetch my data from the database:

```php
public function getRequestPaginator($offset = 0, RequestFilter $filter = null)
    {
        if ($filter == null) {
            $filter = new RequestFilter();
        }
     
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');

        foreach ($filter->getStates() as $key => $value) {
            //preferably I would like to use parameters here too
            $query = $query->orWhere("r.state = '$value'");
        }

        $query = $query
            //this part breaks
            ->orderBy(':order')
            ->setParameter('order', $filter->getOrder())
            //->orderBy('r.' . $filter->getOrder(), $filter->getOrderDirection())
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->setMaxResults($filter->getRequestsPerPage())
            ->getQuery();
        return new Paginator($query);
```

---

Once this code is run in my controller, I get this error at the "orderBy" liner:

Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER, got ':order'

This is the same with numbered parameters ( ?1 instead of :order) and I just can't understand why doctrine is rejecting this when I'm just following the [official documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query).

Here's my doctrine  version:

```json
"doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.6",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.11",
```

I am running PHP 8.1 and symfony 6.0.7 on WAMP.

Thank you in advance for your advice. If this question needs more information, I will provide it quickly !

Comment: I don't think `orderBy` works with parameters. Try something like `->orderBy($filter->getOrder())`

Comment: seems like it , thank you! That's strange though, it's not written anywhere I've looked into. It would seem logical to have parameters everywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @craigh said, I was using parameters inside orderBy(), which does not seem to be supported.
Using

```
->orderBy($filter->getOrder())
```

works.